# How to calculate the median when each value from the data is increased by 10?

Tags: statistics, median

Given that a collection of scores on a quiz leads to a mean of 40, a median of 38, and a mode of 36. If we added 10 points to each score what would be the new median?

Comment: It is $50$, but the justification will vary greatly depending on context.

Answer (score 1):

Originally you have a set of quiz grades: {$q_1, q_2, q_3, ..., q_n$},
then 10 is added to each quiz grade to get a new set: {$q_1+10, q_2+10, q_3+10, ..., q_n+10$}

If the mean was originally 40, the new mean will be 50. 
This can be seen since:
$$\frac{\sum_{i=0}^n q_n+10}{n} =\frac{\sum_{i=0}^n q_n}{n} + \frac{\sum_{i=0}^n 10}{n} = Original\ Mean\ + \frac{10n}{n} = original\ mean\ + 10$$
If the median was originally 38, the new median will be 48.
The median is the middle number in  a set of numbers, therefore if all the numbers are increased by 10, the middle number will be its original value + 10.

If the mode was originally 36, the new mode will be 46.
The mode is the number which appears most often in the set of data, so   all the numbers in the set are increased by 10, the mode will be its old value + 10.

Comment: While we're at it: Adding 10 to each observation makes no change in measures of dispersion such a standard deviation, variance, range, or interquartile range. Suppose the mean age of students in your stat class is 20.4 and the SD is 1.3. If you all get together 10 years from now, then the mean age will be 30.4 and the SD will still be 1.3.